# React 16.12.0. How to build optimized code ES2015?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Where the settings indicate that the building optimized code must be in the ES2015 standard?
In the product.js, the "=>" is replaced to "function()", "let" to "var".

1. React 16.12.0
2. Node.js v12.14.1.
3. npm@6.13.4

create-react-app

"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-autobind": "^1.0.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.3.0"
  },

Comment: Has nothing to do with react itself. What is your build tool?

Comment: If using `create-react-app` maybe [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4421) can help

Comment: I use "create-react-app"